# Is it possible to get a substring from a user defined property in ant?

Tags: regex, ant

I have certain properties defined in a myprop.properties file in the following format:

```
my.first.prop = D:/MyFolder/abc/expanded/myfile.txt
```

In my ant target I can use that string as a property by using `${my.first.prop}` expression. Now I want to obtain the substring before the word `expanded` which is `D:/MyFolder/abc/`

How do I do the same in an ant target?

Solution:Okay after some trials the following regexp gave me the required output-

```
<target name="myTarget">
     <propertyregex
                property="first.part"
                input="${my.first.prop}"
                regexp="(.*)expanded(.*)$"
                select="\1"/>
    <echo>${first.part}</echo>
</target>
```

However, I want to understand the regex I have written what does `(.*)` signify and why is it both before and after `expanded`. Also what does `$` signify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Ant Contrib `PropertyRegex` Task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html):

> Performs regular expression operations on an input string, and sets the results to a property. There are two different operations that can be performed:
>
> - Replacement - The matched regular expression is replaced with a substitition pattern
> - Selection - Groupings within the regular expression are selected via a selection expression.
>
> Expressions are selected in a the same syntax as a regular expression substitution pattern.
>
> ```
> \0 indicates the entire property name (default).
> \1 indicates the first grouping
> \2 indicates the second grouping
> etc...
> ```

`(.*)expanded(.*)$` - says anything before `expanded` and followed by anything.
Hence matches as shown in the bold:
**D:/MyFolder/abc/**`expanded`**/myfile.txt**

You wanted first part of the regex matching group.
`(.*)expanded(.*)$` - regex finds `D:/MyFolder/abc/` as `select="\1"`  attribute of `propertyregex` task.

`select = "\2"` would fetch value `/myfile.txt` which is last match with the given regex against `my.first.prop` property value.

And significance of `$` in regex is that end of string